# Swift iOS 9 QR scanner

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, nsurlrequest

I'm working on a QR scanner in swift which should open a URL and parse the QR data into the URL before loading in a newly made webview.

For that I made a string with my URL and the gets, but adding the scanned data.

When scanning without the function the data is parsed into the label "lblQRCodeResult" with no problem, however at some point when trying to open the webview loading the address, the app crashes.

Any suggestions?

My code for that currently looks like this:

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
            vwQRCode?.frame = CGRectZero
            lblQRCodeResult.text = "NO QRCode text detacted"
            return
        }
        let objMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
        if objMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject.type == AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode {
            let objBarCode = objCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject(objMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject) as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
            vwQRCode?.frame = objBarCode.bounds;
            if objMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject.stringValue != nil {

                let newString = "http://192.168.2.1/qr.php?type=buy&prod=" + objMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject.stringValue;
                lblQRCodeResult.text = newString

                let webV:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height))
                webV.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: newString)!))
                webV.delegate = self;
                self.view.addSubview(webV)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If your app crash, what's the error message?

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to obtain `objBarCode`, you casted the variable as an explicitly unwrapped `AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject`, guaranteeing that it always exist. However, your `objCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` is an optional and the transform function could return a nil object as described in the documentation.

Without the error message it's hard to say, but check if `objBarCode` and the `NSURL` are both valid.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.

```
let newString = "http://192.168.2.1/qr.php?type=buy&prod=" + objMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject.stringValue;

let url = NSString(string: newString)
let urlStr = NSString(string: url.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
let newNS = NSURL(string: urlStr as String)
print(newNS)

//Load URL
webV.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: newNS!))
```